Error While Skipping the Line in OpenCsv Java
public Map<String, List> readCsv(
       MultipartFile customerCsvMultipartFile,
       int chunkSize, int lastOffSet, boolean 
       markReadingCsvProcessComplete ) throws IOException {

    List<CustomerCsvDto> customerCsvData = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, List> migrationCsvMap = new HashMap<>();
    try (InputStreamReader customerCsvReader = new InputStreamReader(customerCsvMultipartFile.getInputStream());)) {
        CsvToBean<CustomerCsvDto> customerCsvToBean = convertInputStreamReaderToCsvBean(CustomerCsvDto.class, customerCsvReader, lastOffSet);
        Iterator<CustomerCsvDto> customerCsvIterator = customerCsvToBean.iterator();          

        while ((customerCsvIterator.hasNext() && lastOffSet < chunkSize) {
            CustomerCsvDto customer = customerCsvIterator.next();
            customerCsvData.add(customer);
            lastOffSet++;
        }
        if (!customerCsvIterator.hasNext()) {
            markReadingCsvProcessComplete = true;
        }
    }

    migrationCsvMap.put("customerCsvData", customerCsvData);
    migrationCsvMap.put("lastOffSet", 
          Collections.singletonList(lastOffSet));
    migrationCsvMap.put("markReadingCsvProcessComplete",
          Collections.singletonList(markReadingCsvProcessComplete));
    return migrationCsvMap;
}

private <T> CsvToBean<T> convertInputStreamReaderToCsvBean(
        Class<T> classToConvert, InputStreamReader 
        inputStreamReader, int lastOffSet) {
    return new CsvToBeanBuilder<T>(inputStreamReader)
            .withType(classToConvert)
            .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
            .withSkipLines(lastOffSet)
            .build();
}

I am trying to read the file in chunks my method takes chunkSize which in my case is 500 lines which i want to process at a time, and lastOffSet measure the index how much file i have read with using .withSkipLines(lastOffSet).
I am trying to skip those lines which are already read but the problem is when i iterate it returns first 500 records correct but then after returns all records with null values.
I am using @CsvBindByName(column = "column_name") to map the columns directly to the Dto.
